# Getting the source code of a page from a googlechrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writting an extension for googlechrome to display a list of items from a website. The problem I have is that I cannot get the source code of the page I am looking for. When I tried putting it in an iframe, it had code that would change the location of the window. XMLhttpRequest is also only allowed on your own domain. Is there any way I can get the source code for a site from a googlechrome extension through javascript?

here is the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/",
    "http://search.twitter.com/"
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Do you need a current site or some external site?

Comment: I am planing to see the source code of an external site. I do not need to edit/run it, only need to see it. I know this is possible because the HTTP Response Browser extension does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all described in details [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html). Long story short:

1. Declare domain permissions in the manifest.
2. Make cross-domain request from a background page.
3. Transfer results to a content script using [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html), if needed.

**UPDATE**

Here is code that works for me:

Manifest - exactly as yours.

popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
            alert(xhr.status); 
            if (xhr.status == 200) { 
                alert(xhr.responseText); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    var url = "http://search.twitter.com/trends/current.json?exclude=hashtags"; 
    xhr.open("GET", url, true); 
    xhr.send();

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this working, 

     alert(req.responseText); 

keeps returning "undefined"

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
  alert(xhr.status);
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
  }
}
var url = "http://search.twitter.com/trends/current.json?exclude=hashtags";
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();

Comment: @DazSlayer Are you running it in a background page? Did you add `http://search.twitter.com/` into manifest permissions?

Comment: I added the site to the manifest permissions and it is running on popup.html. I placed the code in the same place google does it in their helloworld example: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/tutorials/getstarted/popup.html?content-type=text/plain

Comment: @DazSlayer I just run your code and it worked fine (you do have `http://` in your url right?) Can you post your manifest (only not here in comments)?

Comment: this is my manifest file
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/*",
    "http://search.twitter.com/"
  ]
}

Comment: @DazSlayer Does comment parser eat `http://` or you don't have them? Could you please post your manifest into original question, not here.

Comment: @DazSlayer See my edited answer - I created new extension with your manifest and that code and it works. I can't think why it wouldn't work for you. Maybe instead of twitter try some other site.

Comment: ...that is exactly what I have. I have no idea why this is refusing to work with me

Comment: @DazSlayer Dump xhr into console `console.log(xhr)`, maybe there are some errors (you can check console by right clicking on your popup icon and selecting "inspect popup"). You can check network activity there too and see which requests are executing. Also try a different site, maybe it is twitter problem.

Comment: I have already tried other sites. This is the error I am getting:      

XMLHttpRequest cannot load htt p://search.twitter.com/trends/current.json?exclude=hashtags. Origin chrome-extensionhttp://panildedafmbeblddjkijmceecgihlol is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.    Is this a problem with my manifest not giving proper permissions?

Comment: @DazSlayer Sorry, I don't know what it is. Maybe some firewall or security stuff.

Comment: OK I managed to figure out the problem. Running the html page directly will not work because it does not reference the manifest file. You need to run the page as an extension so that it gets permissions from the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

can you run the site in an iframe and then use some javascript to run:

```
sourceCode=[iframename].document.body.parentNode.innerHTML;
sourceCode='<html>'+sourceCode+'</html>'
```

I don't know if this works across domains

Comment: the problem with this is that some sites have javascript that can detect and re-direct if the page is loaded into an iframe